# Fill Null values with mean of previous rows

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Here is my sample data:

```
date,number
2018-06-24,13
2018-06-25,4
2018-06-26,5
2018-06-27,1
2017-06-24,3
2017-06-25,5
2017-06-26,2
2017-06-27,null
2016-06-24,3
2016-06-25,5
2016-06-26,2
2016-06-27,7
2015-06-24,8
2015-06-25,9
2015-06-26,12
2015-06-27,13
```

I need to fill null values with mean of previous year data. 
That is if `'2017-06-27'` is null value, I need to fill it with mean of `"2016-06-27"` and `'2015-06-27'` data.

output

```
date,number
2018-06-24,13
2018-06-25,4
2018-06-26,5
2018-06-27,1
2017-06-24,3
2017-06-25,5
2017-06-26,2
2017-06-27,10
2016-06-24,3
2016-06-25,5
2016-06-26,2
2016-06-27,7
2015-06-24,8
2015-06-25,95
2015-06-26,12
2015-06-27,13
```

I used below code but it gives me mean of everything in a perticular partition.

Extracted date and month columns

```
wingrp = Window.partitionBy('datee','month')
df = df.withColumn("TCount",avg(df["Count"]).over(wingrp))
```

Comment: Hey Ashu, can you show us what you have tried? Right now, your question gives the impression that you're just hoping people here will write code for you. Have you looked at Window functions?

Comment: updated the quetsion, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is a step in the right direction (even though you’re not showing the columns you’ve added). You’ll want to partition by the month and the day of the month in your window, sort the resulting windows by the date column (so basically by year) and then limit the window to all preceding rows. Like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

schema = StructType([
    StructField("date", DateType(), True),
    StructField("number", IntegerType(), True)
])

df = spark.read.csv("your_data.csv",
                    header=True,
                    schema=schema)

wind = (Window
        .partitionBy(month(df.date), dayofmonth(df.date))
        .orderBy("date")
        .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
        )

result = (df
          .withColumn("result",
                      coalesce(df.number, avg(df.number).over(wind)))
          )
```